# Getting Asp.Net forms authentication to use 403 custom error page instead of login page

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, custom-error-pages

I've a got an Asp.Net site that is using Forms authentication, I've also got custom errors configured in the web.config. One of these is a special error page for 403's (access denied). My question is how do I get Forms authentication to work smarter?

I would like Forms authentication to send users to login page only if they are not authenticated. If they are I want it to defer to the custom error pages that i've defined in the web.config. This seems like something very basic, how can this be achieved?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".TTCookie" loginUrl="Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="43200" />
</authentication>

<customErrors mode="On">
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/ErrorPages/403.aspx"/>
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/404.aspx"/>
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/500.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

What i'm observing with the above configuration is that when I hit a page I don't have access to it kicks me back to login.aspx even though i'm already authenticated.